# Why bother with certain types of 2fa if they can be easily bypassed?

Tags: authentication, passwords, exploit, multi-factor, user-education

In the wild, there is a method of bypassing 2fa.  The gist of it is that the attacker doesn't just phish the password, but they also phish the 2nd factor and use those for a real login on their own machine. (described in detail here https://www.wandera.com/bypassing-2fa/).  In this attack scenario, 2fa gives a false sense of security and makes it more likely to fall victim to phishing.  After all if my only protection against getting phished is checking the certificate and URL, then I'll be more likely to double check it compared to just having bought into a brand new shiny 2nd factor that touts itself to be fool proof.

If I get phished like this with the 2nd factor, the hacker is in and as long as they don't log out, they can stay in for a very long time causing all kinds of trouble.

Clearly the 2fa has a disadvantage of creating a false sense of security.   The only advantages I could see is for users who share the same password across different services or for making subsequent logins using the same credentials impossible.  Aren't those advantages too small relative to the disadvantage?

Obviously the answer here is re-education.  Tell users to use 2fa but be keep being vigilant - make them aware of this type of attack and how nasty it is even with 2fa.  But that's hard to do considering how many 2fa solutions are pushed as "THE" ultimate final solution for phishing.  It's just not true and in many ways it makes the problem worse - especially for websites.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see they don't mention that U2F and webauthn _do_ prevent this sort of phishing, which isn't surprising considering that they're in the business of blocking phishing domains.

Comment: You are right U2F is better, but it's interesting that it faces some challenges: https://www.yubico.com/support/security-advisories/ysa-2018-02/

Comment: Thanks for that link, I hadn't seen that! I would note though that that's an implementation issue, not an issue with the protocol itself. Implementation issues are always a concern, but they can be fixed much easier than a design flaw (and as you can see it was fixed relatively quickly).

Comment: Indeed, this isn't actually anything new.  2FA over SMS has been effectively "deprecated" as a security measure for a while now, and google in particular (who I mention because that is what they use a an example in your linked article) has been trying to move users over to new 2FA methods for a while: https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-wants-you-to-stop-using-its-sms-two-factor-sign-in/

Comment: Google's improved prompts are good.  I also like the "is this me?" question.  Much better than just hitting allow/deny in other authenticators.  But, it's still just a stop gap. Given that botnets span the entire globe it should be easy for the MitM to intercept device and browser info and spoof it.  Then you just have to proxy to the closest bot (relative to the real user) and you're good.  User won't be able to tell the difference at all.

Comment: There could be non-security related reasons. A sense of security, even if false, is a way to gather/retain customers or charge extra. Some businesses might want to link profiles to phone numbers. Maybe they want to deter account sharing or one person using multiple accounts. Or SMS 2FA may "feel" more secure even if it's not and removing it may lose customers.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that this raises the bar for attackers - they need to implement a more complex system for an attack to succeed. By increasing the cost, you shut out less-resourced attackers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, TOTP and HOTP (in addition to email, SMS, etc) are vulnerable to this. Why do we use them? Because they're easy to implement, and they *do* provide *some* protection. As long as the majority of people aren't using *any* sort of 2nd factor, phishers will predominantly target those users, as MitM phishing (debatably) takes more effort.

I've said it before and I'll say it again, once most people have started using 2FA for their important accounts, this sort of MitM phishing will become much more common. The way to prevent this is U2F or WebAuthn, which both use [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to authenticate to the server, and communicate with the browser to verify that the domain name you've visited matches the domain you registered the key for.

If you want to see a longer and (in my opinion) less biased blog post on the issue, I skimmed this [Evilginx 2 blog post](https://breakdev.org/evilginx-2-next-generation-of-phishing-2fa-tokens/) and it seems to cover everything pretty well (and even has some stuff about how phishing domains can avoid scanners that try to block them).

I was focused on phishing, but [as Ajedi32 points out](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/193180/151903), 2FA is useful for more than just preventing phishing. It's useful whenever your password may be compromised but the second factor isn't.

Comment: Would you say that OTP 2fa is not designed to protect against this? ie OTP is meant to prove the identity of the end user, not the identity of the server. I suppose this would still be a false sense of security if these 2FA methods are marketed as "Prevent your accounts from being hacked!"

Comment: Yup.  If you have to put a code in a website then it can be phished, although that is still much harder than hacking an account without any 2FA.  I'm also a big fan of U2F and webauth, although there are also other 2FA methods that can't be phished.  It's really just about "out of band" verification, and the google authenticator app also manages it well for services that use it properly.  In that case the service essentially pings your phone which asks you to verify your login, and then the app communicates directly with the service - no code entry or anything that can be phished.

Comment: @ConorMancone Hmm, does the "server pings your phone, phone responds to server" make it phish-proof? I think the attack being described is a transparent MitM where you enter your credentials to the phishing site which then opens a session to the real site. So you believe you are logging in to facebook (but actually giving your password to the phishing site), seconds later you get a "Are you trying to log in?" from facebook; you have no idea these are actually two separate, unrelated sessions.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth yes, and it was specifically designed for that use-case.  This doesn't stop you from entering your credentials on the fake site of course.  However, when the fake site opens a session with the real site, and the real site initiates 2FA, the site in question "directly" communicates with the phone for verification.  All the user does is press "Yes" or "No" on their app.  There is no further communication over the MitM site, and therefore the 2FA cannot be intercepted (hence why I referred to it as "out of band" verification)

Comment: @ConorMancone But the phisher still gets into your account. Why does it matter if the 2FA is intercepted or not?

Comment: @ConorMancone The 2FA isn't intercepted, but the session that's being authenticated is still the phisher's session isn't it? Is there some standard or paper we can read on this? I'm interested in it as well.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth If someone has your credentials but can't complete the 2FA verification, then they don't have your account and can't log in.  Granted, you probably still want to change your password, but that's the whole point of 2FA.  You need the password and the second authentication token.  With only one you can't get in.  SMS codes are phishable because when the MitM site uses your credentials to login to the real service, the real service sends a code, and then the MitM site asks for the code.  With out-of-band authentication that isn't possible.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Without the 2FA being intercepted then the attacker never actually gets in.  They do have your password of course, but they are still locked out.  I was trying to find some better details on how these out-of-band verifications work, but so far all I can find is fluff pieces: https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-wants-you-to-stop-using-its-sms-two-factor-sign-in/ https://duo.com/product/trusted-users/two-factor-authentication/authentication-methods/duo-push  I use the google authenticator myself, and it works well

Comment: @ConorMancone What I think Mike Ounsworth and I are unclear on is how the legitimate user logs in. We (or at least I) am/are thinking of a user on a desktop browser, who then uses their phone or a hardware token as a second factor. Does this push notification method only work for authenticating directly from the phone itself, so it doesn't apply to the desktop scenario?

Comment: I'm not actually sure the Desktop / Phone distinction matters. @ConorMancone Please tell my why this attack scenario doesn't work: User browses to phishing site, believing they are on the real site, which shows the usual "Please enter password, 2FA will be conducted out of band". They enter their password. Phisher then (within the second) goes to the real site and enters their password. The user gets a push notification on their phone saying "Are you trying to log in?". They click Yes because they are trying to log in. Phisher is now in to their account.

Comment: @ConorMancone I see in the screenshot from the zdnet article that it's doing a GeoIP lookup, so that's at least a warning sign if the phisher has an IP from a different region. If it works how I'm thinking it does though it's not foolproof.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Might not be following your question perfectly, but I think this answers it.  The phone effectively becomes your second factor.  To walk through an example, I could walk over to my wife's computer and try to login to my gmail account.  After putting in my credentials it will pause on the 2FA screen.  The app on my phone will then popup and ask me to verify that I am trying to log in.  I will then hit yes on my phone, and the google login page will automatically refresh and grant me access to my gmail account on her computer.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth that's a good point I hadn't considered.  The google login flow provides specific information about who is trying to login (browser, geoip location, etc...) so a diligent user can see there is a problem, but it's not foolproof

Answer (score 4):

Because 2FA protects against more than just phishing.

One major threat 2FA protects against is [credential stuffing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Credential_stuffing), where attackers take passwords stolen from other services in data breaches and try using those same credentials to log in to your account. Credential stuffing is a fairly common cause of account compromise, with [numerous instances](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Credential_stuffing#Examples) of successful attacks occurring over the years.

As you said, it's true that attack doesn't work if you use unique, randomly-generated passwords for each site; but then again phishing doesn't work either if you only ever enter your password on the site you originally signed up on. The fact that it's possible for diligent users to defend against both those attacks doesn't mean they're no longer a problem.

2FA also protects against many other bad practices which commonly afflict password-based authentication, such as weak passwords, passwords written down on post-it notes attached to the user's monitor, etc.

Additionally, 2FA also provides limited resistance against other attacks such as keylogging and phishing by forcing the attacker to use the captured credentials immediately and limiting the duration of compromise to a single login session. There are also some, much better forms of 2FA such as U2F/WebAuthN tokens which provide strong defense against phishing, as they integrate with the user's browser and can therefore ensure credentials are only ever provided to the site they were intended to be used for.